# Socket.io keeps multiple connected sockets alive for 1 client

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am using Socket.io to connect a React client to a Node.js server and the `query` option in socket.io to identify uniquely every new client. However, the server creates multiple sockets for every client and, when I need to send something from the server, I don't know which socket use, because I have more than one, and all of them are connected.

The client code:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
...
const socket = io(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '?userID=' + userID, { forceNew: true });

socket.on('connect', () => {
        socket.on('new-order', data => {
            const { add_notification } = this.props;
            add_notification(data);
        });
```

The server code:

```
....
server = http
        .createServer(app)
        .listen(8080, () => console.log(env + ' Server listening on port 8080'));
io = socketIo(server);

io.on('connection', socket => {
    const userID = socket.handshake.query.userID;
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        socket.removeAllListeners();
    });
});
```

And here the server-side that emits events to the client:

```
for (const socketID in io.sockets.connected) {
    const socket = io.sockets.connected[socketID];
    if (socket.handshake.query.userID === userID) {
        // Here, I find more than one socket for the same condition, always connected.
        socket.emit(event, data)
    }
}
```

Here, it is possible to see all these socket for the same client:

[image]

I tried to send events for all socket from a given `userID`, however, multiple events are triggered to the client, showing duplicated data to the user. I also tried to send events to the last socket, but, sometimes it works, sometimes doesn't.

Someone have a clue how to uniquely identify a socket when there are several clients?

Comment: what are these values? `socket.handshake.query.userID` and `userID` maybe they're both undefined which will be true multiple times per socket

Comment: You send the reply on the socket the request came from. If there are multiple sockets it is because the client send multiple requests.

Comment: @azium, when I do this in the client `io(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '?userID=' + userID`, it fills out the `socket.handshake.query.userID` in the server. So, for each socket, I have this identifier from its client. In fact, I am not using it at that time, I am only showing how to identify the client.

Comment: @user207421 I didn't get what you wrote. I am not replying the client. It connects and becomes idle, waiting for some notification from the server. This isn't a chat, the server only send data to client when something happen on backend.

Comment: is `userID` unique? maybe multiple sockets have the same id

Comment: Each client has an unique `userID`, but each socket has its own `id` (see in the bottom of the image). I am searching through several sockets which one has the `userID` that came from client, but, I find multiple sockets with different `ids` but same `userID` and, some of them, do not reply to the client anymore.

Comment: what's generating the `userID` ?

Comment: The userID is generated client side, when the user logs in. It isn't related to the socket directly, but I am using it to know which client is connected to the server.